# How to print the value of class variables without instantiating the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Class example:

```
class Cls1:
  a=10
  b=20
```

Expected output:

```
{a:10, b:20}
```

Note: I can instantiate the class and use vars function to get the above output. But I need to see the class variable values without instantiating the class.

Comment: `vars(Cls1)`, and filter out the dunderscore values…?

Answer (score 4):

Try `Cls1.__dict__` or `vars(Cls1)`

You can separate them with `__`

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in vars(Cls1).items() if not k.startswith("__")}        
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
```

Answer (score 2):

They're class attributes, not instance attributes.

```
>>> Cls1.a
10
>>> Cls1.b
20
```

Classes have other attributes besides the ones you define explicitly, so `vars(Cls1)` will give you a lot of stuff you don't want. Best to be explicit:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in vars(Cls1).items() if k in ['a', 'b']}
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
```

or

```
>>> {k: getattr(Cls1, k) for k in ['a', 'b']}
```

Classes aren't supposed to be used as containers. If you want a container, use a `dict` in the first place.

Comment: I want the output as: {a:10, b:20}

Comment: `{a:Cls1.a, b: Cls1.b}`

Comment: Needs to me dynamic not hardcoded

Comment: @variable You can't really do that, because you'd have a bunch of stuff you need to filter out. *Why* do you need to extract the class variables like this?

Comment: But using container like dict wont give me an autocomplete feature. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Autocompletion should not be what you design your code around. Use a `dict`.

Comment: Whatever is doing your autocompletion may eventually take type hints into account; see [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) to predefine what keys the dict should have.